# read.csv is extremely slow in reading csv files with large numbers of columns

Tags: r, csv

I have a .csv file: example.csv with 8000 columns x 40000 rows. The csv file have a string header for each column. All fields contains integer values between 0 and 10. When I try to load this file with read.csv it turns out to be extremely slow. It is also very slow when I add a parameter nrow=100. I wonder if there is a way to accelerate the read.csv, or use some other function instead of read.csv to load the file into memory as a matrix or data.frame?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please share the code you are using to read.csv - there are a lot of options for improving performance, see ?read.table

Answer (score 19):

If your CSV only contains integers, you should use `scan` instead of `read.csv`, since `?read.csv` says:

```
 ‘read.table’ is not the right tool for reading large matrices,
 especially those with many columns: it is designed to read _data
 frames_ which may have columns of very different classes.  Use
 ‘scan’ instead for matrices.
```

Since your file has a header, you will need `skip=1`, and it will probably be faster if you set `what=integer()`.  If you must use `read.csv` and speed / memory consumption are a concern, setting the `colClasses` argument is a huge help.

Comment: You can add the names of your columns back by reading the single line of he header as a vector with the `readLines()` function and modifying the column names of your matrix.

Comment: Thanks. I just found another wrapper function make use of scan(): read.matrix function in tseries package. It claims that it is faster than read.csv.

Answer (score 17):

Try using `data.table::fread()`. This is by far on of the fastest ways to read `.csv` files into R. There is a [good benchmark here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1727772/quickly-reading-very-large-tables-as-dataframes-in-r).

```
library(data.table)

data <- fread("c:/data.csv")
```

If you want to make it even faster, you can also read only the subset of columns you want to use:

```
data <- fread("c:/data.csv", select = c("col1", "col2", "col3"))
```

Comment: fread crashes instantly on my data (has a little over a million columns)

Comment: This is strange; I would recommend you uninstall and reinstall the library: ´remove.packages("data.table") ; install.packages("data.table")´ . If the problem persists, you might wanna consider opening an ´issue´ on the project website https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki

Comment: Instant crashing seem to suggest you don't have sufficient free memory to read the data.

Answer (score 6):

Also try Hadley Wickham's `readr` package:

```
library(readr) 
data <- read_csv("file.csv")
```

Answer (score 4):

If you'll read the file often, it might well be worth saving it from R in a binary format using the `save` function. Specifying `compress=FALSE` often results in faster load times.

...You can then load it in with the (surprise!) `load` function.

```
d <- as.data.frame(matrix(1:1e6,ncol=1000))
write.csv(d, "c:/foo.csv", row.names=FALSE)

# Load file with read.csv
system.time( a <- read.csv("c:/foo.csv") ) # 3.18 sec

# Load file using scan
system.time( b <- matrix(scan("c:/foo.csv", 0L, skip=1, sep=','), 
                         ncol=1000, byrow=TRUE) ) # 0.55 sec

# Load (binary) file using load
save(d, file="c:/foo.bin", compress=FALSE)
system.time( load("c:/foo.bin") ) # 0.09 sec
```

Comment: Whether compression speeds things depends on multiple factors and can be tested on a /file /machine basis.  HD speed, CPU speed, and degree of compression achieved all contribute to whether the compressed or uncompressed file is faster to load.  But in general, uncompressed can be faster when drive speed is good and CPU speed isn't while the opposite is true for compressed.  For example, I'd tend to want to use compressed writing to USB flash drives on a fast laptop.

Answer (score 2):

Might be worth it to try the new [`vroom`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/vroom/index.html) package

> `vroom` is a new approach to reading delimited and fixed width data into R.
>
> It stems from the observation that when parsing files reading data from disk and finding the delimiters is generally not the main bottle neck. Instead (re)-allocating memory and parsing the values into R data types (particularly for characters) takes the bulk of the time.
>
> Therefore you can obtain very rapid input by first performing a fast indexing step and then using the [ALTREP](https://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2018/04/r-350.html) (ALTernative REPresentations) framework available in R versions 3.5+ to access the values in a lazy / delayed fashion.
>
> This approach potentially also allows you to work with data that is larger than memory. As long as you are careful to avoid materializing the entire dataset at once it can be efficiently queried and subset.

```
#install.packages("vroom", 
#                 dependencies = TRUE, repos = "https://cran.rstudio.com")
library(vroom)

df <- vroom('example.csv')
```

[**Benchmark:**](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/vroom/vignettes/benchmarks.html) `readr` vs `data.table` vs `vroom` for a 1.57GB file

[image]