Loading & Analyzing Big Data from a CSV in R
Please forgive me if this is a duplicate or poorly written. I can't seem to find the resources I need.
I have a two-terabyte CSV that I need to analyze in R in various ways, but I am unsure how to load this amount of data for analysis. To be clear, I don't need help analyzing the data, but help working with this size CSV.
The end goals of the analysis are yet to be defined, but I assume summary statistics over multiple periods will need to be performed, as well as determining trends/seasonality.
For context, the data is years of hourly consumption from thousands of meters. The basic data structure is a meter ID column, a date-time stamp, and meter characteristics.
Any suggestions on how to go about this? Looking for packages, YouTube videos, guides, anything helpful...

https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/HighPerformanceComputing.html

"end goals are undefined" makes this off-topic/very hard to answer.

Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38536226/r-reading-a-huge-csv or maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68628271/partially-read-really-large-csv-gz-in-r-using-vroom/68693819

I think the question "How do I load a 2TB CSV?" is potentially answerable. (and more context would be nice, e.g. what hardware you're using, what structure the data has, etc.) The edits are helpful, but we're still arguably too far from your situation to know how to be helpful.

Here's a great resource on analyzing time series. https://otexts.com/fpp3/ You might look at the feasts package for feature extraction from time series. But problem 1 is you have an insanely big CSV file, and everything else will be easier if you can put that in a database or convert to some parquet files so that you can query the data efficiently.

Here are just my views.

2TB csv file could easily expand to more than 5TB data.frame when loaded to R, most computers or HPCs have difficulty allocating this much memory.
I would use readLines() to sample a minimal example for basic analysis, as readLines() doesn't load entire data into memory.
For easy query and summary purposes, you can try to load data into the database, such as SQL, NoSQL, etc. Here is a link how to do so.
There are R packages to interact with various databases. My personal favorite is DBI.

