# data.table::fread() is crashing for bigger csv files

Tags: r, csv, data.table

I am processing big **csv** file (~500-700MB), so I am reading them chunk by chunk. I tried read.csv() function but it is very slow as number to rows to skip increases, so I found `data.table::fread()` a much faster way to read a file.([R-Blogger](https://www.r-bloggers.com/efficiency-of-importing-large-csv-files-in-r/),and [stackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7327851/read-csv-is-extremely-slow-in-reading-csv-files-with-large-numbers-of-columns)) but when I am reading a 60MB `csv` file with fread() it works fine [image: (Reading 60MB file)] but when I tried it on a bigger file (~450MB) of same type it shows **R Session Aborted** 
[image: (Reading 450MB file)] both files have same structure, it only differs in size. I am not able to understand why it is not working as people are reading even bigger size file with it.

Here is my code snippet-

```
library(data.table)
ffName = "Bund001.csv"

s<- Sys.time()


ColNamesVector <<- c("RIC","Date","Time","GMT_Offset","Type","Price","Volume","Bid_Price","Bid_Size","Ask_Price","Ask_Size","Qualifiers")


rawData <- fread(ffName,sep=",",nrows = 100000,skip = 400000,col.names = ColNamesVector)



print(Sys.time()-s)
```

Comment: Can you track RAM utilization before crash? How much RAM do you have on your computer?

Comment: Currently 8GB RAM is Installed in my PC, Before Running The script, it was `rsession = 65,880k` and `rstudio = 160,328k` after crash `rstudio = 157,060k` and `rsession = 66,196k` before crashing and disappearing from task manager window.  I don't think RAM utilization is a issue  as I am able to read 500MB-700MB of **csv** files with `read.csv()` and `read.csv.raw()`

Comment: Ok then, i guees there is something wrong after few lines in your set. `fread`is known to be sensitive. You should control that there are no missing separators, nor special characters in your large file.

Comment: about missing separators, this is counter statement which works perfectly fine
`rawData <- read.csv("Bund001.csv",sep = ",",nrows = chSize,skip = nskip,col.names = ColNamesVector)`

Comment: so is there any way to get it worked out, or any other faster way to read **csv** files?

Comment: You are able to read the whole file by chunks? (Ex: line 1 to 10k, 10001 to 20k... until the end?)

Comment: Why do you use `<<-` and not just `<-` for creating `ColNamesVector`?

Comment: @Emmanuel-Lin yes, and by reading chunk by chunk I meant, first I'm reading 100000 lines, processing them and saving data then again repeating the same from 100001 on-words.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you check [NEWS](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/NEWS.md) first?  (Other tips are on the data.table [Support page](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Support).)

The screenshot included in your question shows you are using 1.10.4. As luck would have it, currently NEWS shows that 14 improvements have been made to `fread` since then and many are relevant to your question. Please try dev. The [installation page](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation) explains that a pre-compiled binary for Windows is made for you and how to get it. You don't need to have any tools installed. That page explains you can revert easily should it not work out.

Please try v1.10.5 from dev and accept this answer if that fixes it.

Comment: I much appreciate your answer, but I'm currently in my internship and these people have GitHub blocked for us, Due to some reasons that nobody else can understand :P. I installed the  v1.10.4(current version on my R ) from CRAN using `install.packages()`.  I will try the the  v1.10.5 during weekends and get back to you with updates, Thanks again.

Comment: @AbhinavRawat My sympathies. Perhaps you can use your phone to view the homepage. Here's a direct link to the pre-compiled Windows binary (current 1.10.5) : https://ci.appveyor.com/api/buildjobs/g0hw382c9i9iuujj/artifacts/data.table_1.10.5.zip

Comment: I have the same problem with `fread`. It works with `nrows = 900000`, but not with `nrows = 1000000`. It also causes R session to abort. I am using R 3.6.2. and data.table 1.12.8. I have it works with read.csv2 (muck slower ofc).

Answer (score -3):

It is not about size, it means your CSV is slightly out-of-specs.

I would advice to try `readr`, it is a bit slower but more tolerant to errors

https://github.com/tidyverse/readr