# Issue when I try do download a large csv file from dropbox using the read.csv2 function

Tags: r, dropbox, read.csv

I have an issue when I try to download a large csv file (170 Mo) from dropbox.

Here is an example of my code :

```
read.csv2("https://www.dropbox.com/s/m2hkvgcf7zmkdym/example.csv?dl=1", 
quote = "", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

I get the following error message :

> "maximum delay of 60 seconds reached"

It seems there is a limit of time to download the file. After this limit is reached, the execution stops.
I have no problems to download smaller csv files.

Answer (score 0):

Try the `vroom` package, which really speeds up the process of loading your data (from 145s to 45s on my computer).
See: [read.csv is extremely slow in reading csv files with large numbers of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7327851/read-csv-is-extremely-slow-in-reading-csv-files-with-large-numbers-of-columns)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, very useful ! and yes it is faster than read.csv2 and it enables to download the file.